# ImportError: No module named if trying to execute from command line

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I am getting following error

```
D:\pythongui>C:\Python27\python.exe D:/pythongui/controller/MainController.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/pythongui/controller/MainController.py", line 5, in <module>
from view.MainView import Launcher
ImportError: No module named view.MainView
```

when I am executing the following command in terminal

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:/pythongui/controller/MainController.py
```

But the same code is working in pycharm without any error.

My Directory structure is as follows :

[image]

I have tried following code

```
import GetMyIp as getMyIP
import sys
sys.path.append("view/MainView")
import Server as server
import view.MainView
```

Comment: In PyCharm the ´view´ is contained within the PATH.
From your commandline, this appears not to be the case.

Comment: @Uvar   Thanks for reply, is there way to add it in PATH.

Comment: import sys
sys.path.append(PATH)
Where path is the relevant path.

Comment: @Uvar I have tried the way you suggested, but the issue is still there, I have added the code I tried, please have a look

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer. Somehow missed the comment.
PATH = "D:/pythongui/view" <- explicitly reference the full path. But I guess this comment came too late to be of any use..